# How to return value in OnCompleteListener for Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to get GPS of smartphone like the following code:

In **`Activity.java`** , I use the following code to get **GPS**.

```
private GPSClass gps;
gps.getGPSLocation();
```

In **`GPSClass.java`**

```
public void getGPSLocation(){
        FusedLocationProviderClient mLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext);
        mLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(mContext, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    mLocation = task.getResult();
                    Log.i("getLocation---LOCATION", mLocation.getLatitude() + "/"
                            + mLocation.getLongitude());

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But how to return value in **`GPSClass.java`** ?

I have try to replace

```
public void onComplete
```

instead of

```
public Location onComplete
```

But it show the error

`'onComplete(Task<Location>)' in 'Anonymous class derived from com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener' clashes with 'onComplete(Task<TResult>)' in 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener'; attempting to use incompatible return type`

Did I miss something?  How to return value in `OnCompleteListener`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have the value in `mLocation`? Why would you want to return it. It's already there.

Comment: I want to get `mLocation` from other class.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a callback e.g.

```
public void getGPSLocation(GPSCallback callback){
        FusedLocationProviderClient mLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext);
        mLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(mContext, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    mLocation = task.getResult();
                    Log.i("getLocation---LOCATION", mLocation.getLatitude() + "/"
                            + mLocation.getLongitude());
                    callback.onLocation(mLocation);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Create an Interface called `GPSCallback` e.g.

```
interface GPSCallback{
void onLocation(Location location);
}
```

and call the method with the callback

```
gps.getGPSLocation(new GPSCallback() {
    void onLocation(Location location) {
        // do what you need to do with the location
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a system of callback, and you cannot mix a direct-returning method with a callback.

You seem to want a simple method that directly gives you the location, but as you can see `FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()` returns a `Task` and not a direct value. Because of that, when you call your method  using `getGPSLocation()`, you have to wait for the completion of the task to retrieve the value.

If you want a simple solution, you can directly call the `FusedLocationProviderClient`  in your activity, instead of creating another class :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(){

        mLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext);
        mLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(mContext, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    handleLocation(task.getResult();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleLocation(Location location){
        //Do your handling here
    }
}
```